# How to print contents of a file in c?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, fopen

I'm stuck on the first half of this c program that I'm writing with vim on cygwin where I need to print the contents of a file to standard output. I just want to be sure that my getNextWord function is working properly but when I compile I get errors that I'll show after the code. Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int MAX_WORD_LEN = 256;

char* getNextWord(FILE* fd) {
    char c;
    char wordBuffer[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    int putChar = 0;

    while((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF) {
        if(isalum(c)) break;
    }
    if (c == EOF) return NULL;

    wordBuffer[putChar++] = tolower(c);

    while((c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF) {
        if(isspace(c) || putChar >= MAX_WORD_LEN -1) break;

        if(isalum(c)) {
            wordBuffer[putChar++] = tolower(c);
        }
    }
    wordBuffer[putChar] = '\0';
    return strdup(wordBuffer);
}

int main() {
    char filename[50];
    printf("Enter the file name: \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    getNextWord(file);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

So here's what I see in the shell, the next line shows command line:

```
$gcc words.c -o words

/tmp/ccku5u4f.o:words.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to 'isalum'

/tmp/ccku5u4f.o:words.c:(.text+0x70): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against 
 undefined symbol 'isalum'

/tmp/ccku5u4f.o:words.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to 'isalum'

/tmp/ccku5u4f.o:words.c:(.text+0xfd): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against 
 undefined symbol 'isalum'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /tmp/cc/ko5u4f.o: 
 bad reloc address 0x0 in section '.pdata'

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: final l ink failed: 
 Invalid operation

collect2: error: ld return 1 exit status
```

I am absolutely clueless as to what to do about these errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is definition of isalum

Comment: Compile with warnings e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o foo foo.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `isalnum` instead of `isalum`...

Comment: Wow... thank you very much. Now it compiles fine but I'm getting nothing on the console after running. How do I use my getNextWord function to actually show output?